# How to migrate domain from site on Azure to Traffic Manager without downtime

Tags: azure, domain-name, traffic-management

I'm trying to figure out how to migrate my live site from a single instance on Azure to a multi-server traffic manager solution.  Specifically, I need to know how to migrate the domain name so the site remains up and doesn't go down.

I am using the domain on the single instance and need to add the domain to the new regional sites, but Azure tells me that the domain is already in use.

Do I add cnames in DNS to allow for the additional site before I direct to the traffic manager, or what?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, when you say site, is it an Azure Website (Web APP) that you have configured? are you looking to deploy the website to multiple regions?

Comment: Yes.  I've created new web apps in other regions and now want the traffic manager to distribute traffic across each of the regional sites.